# Why does select2, on edit, show the first id found on dropdown, when the id is correctly selected?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

**Tools used:**

1. Visual studio Comunity 2022
2. Bootstrap
3. Select2
   4.Javascript

**1.Explaination**

I am using Select2 for simplified dropdown search, of client names,the dropdown is inside a popup.
If i use just bootstrap and javascript, the id/name is picked up and shown correctly.
When i enable/use select2, it shows the first id/name on the list, but if i click the dropdown i can see that the id/name is correctly selected.

I tried to look for a solution on the select2 website and on the web, but have not found anything suitable yet.

**2. Question**

What am i missing in the code below?

**3.The code**

```
                            <form id="Edit" method="post" asp-page-handler="Edit">
                            <partial name="_EditPopupPartial" />

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                                <div class="form-group" hidden>
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="Orders.OrdId" class="form-control fw-bold " id="xOrdIdpopup1" />
                                    <select asp-for="Orders.OrdId" class="form-control fw-bold" asp-items="ViewBag.OrdId">
                                    </select>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Orders.OrdId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group m-0">
                                    <label asp-for="Orders.OrdDate" class="border-0 m-0" >Date</label>
                                    <input asp-for="Orders.OrdDate" class="form-control fw-bold "
                                           style="font-size:80%;" type="date" id="xDateIdpopup1" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Orders.OrdDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group m-0">
                                    <label asp-for="Orders.CliId" class="border-0 m-0" >Client</label>
                                    <select asp-for="Orders.CliId" class="form-select clientedit select2-container selectdata custom-select fw-bold "
                                            asp-items="ViewBag.CliId" style="font-size:80%;overflow:auto;" id="xCliIdpopup1">                                           
                                    </select>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Orders.CliId" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Orders.FurtherNotes" class="border-0 m-0" >Notes</label>
                                    <input asp-for="Orders.FurtherNotes" class="form-control fw-bold text-c" id="xNotesIdpopup1" type="text" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Orders.FurtherNotes" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>

                                <partial name="_BtnEditPopupPartial" />

                            </div>
                        </form>
                        
                        
                            <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

         $('.clientedit').select2({
            width: '100%',
            dropdownParent: $('#editOrderModal'),
            minimumResultsForSearch: 10
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Fillo, did you mean, it always displays the first option as selected when the page loaded. And  it works fine when you select the option.

Comment: Hi @Rena. When i click Edit, on the dropdown, it shows the first ID, but when i click this dropdown and go look for the value that i have previously selected, it shows that in blue/gray. Which means that the value has been correctly picked. I want the chosen value to be shown as the first/selected value in the dropdownlist, as it would normally behave in a simple dropdownlist. Why does not select2 show the selected value as the first value in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Hi @Fillo, I have tested your code and it works fine with the correct value displayed. What is your jQuery and select2 version?

Comment: Hi @Rena, i have  jQuery JavaScript Library v3.6.0   and  Select2 4.0.13